# Display selected records on message box in the Form of Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a form in MS Access 2013.

[image: form]

After enter the information, select the parts and click the **SEND** button, parts will be sent out (insert into Table B and delete from Table A).

I would like to display selected records on the message box before the parts sending out.

[image: message box]

Is it possible? If not, could you please recommend another way for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: would it be possible to post your code for your first Image?
I want in my Report only entries I selected in this msgBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I suppose the data is stored in a table? You can use vba on the on click event of the button as follows :

```
private sub buttonSend_onclick()
    Dim rs as recordset
    Dim s as string

    s = "Select * from [TableName] Where [SelectFieldName] = True"
    Set rs = Currentdb.openrecordset(s)
    s = ""
    While not rs.eof
        s = s & rs("[PartIdFieldName]") & ", "
        rs.movenext
    wend
    if s <> "" then
        s = left(s,len(s) - 2)
        s = s & "."
    else
        Msgbox "No parts selected"
    end if

    s = "Deliver parts below?" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & s
    if(msgbox(s,vbYesNo) = vbYes) then
        ''proceed with the send
    else
        ''do not proceed with the send
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: You're fantastic!!! Salute! If you have time, could you please take a look of another question of mine at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892754/increase-the-font-size-of-message-box-in-microsoft-access-2013 Thanks in advance!