# Increase the font size of message box in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to increase the font size of message box in Access 2013 via vba code?

From this

[image: small]

to this

[image]

Some users are over 40 years old. They require a bigger size of font for viewing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The font size of system error boxes is a system control and would need to be changed on all individual computers.

You could instead trap the error in VBA and display your own messages via a UserForm, which would allow you to control the message and the font.

So, instead of

```
If countDuplicate > 0 Then
    MsgBox _
        "A record of this Part ID already exist. No changes can be made.", _
        vbCritical, _
        "Duplicated Record"
    Me.Undo
End If
```

You would have the following:

```
If countDuplicate > 0 Then
    frm_AlreadyExists.Show
    Me.Undo
End If
```

Where `frm_AlreadyExists` is a form that you would create and would have the message you listed above.

That should get you started. As a further step, instead of having a separate `UserForm` for each error, you could create an error table that would contain `Error ID`, `Error Message`, `Error Type`, `Error Title` columns.

```
Error ID    Error Message                 Error Type    Error Title         Button Action   Button Text
1           A record ... already exist.   Critical      Duplicated Record   SubName1        Click Here
2           ... not a valid EMPLOYEE      Critical      Invalid GID         SubName2        Click Here
```

Then you would call the `UserForm` with the following:

```
If countDuplicate > 0 Then
    ErrorID = 1 'You'll need to declare this variable elsewhere in your code
    frm_AlreadyExists.Show
End If
```

And the code to initialize the `UserForm` (in the UserForm code module)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lErrorID        As Long
    Dim sErrorMessage   As String
    Dim sErrorType      As String
    Dim sErrorTitle     As String
    Dim sBtnText        As String

    lErrorID = errorID

''Look up the following from the Error Table
    'sErrorMessage = Result from lookup
    'sErrorType = Result from lookup
    'sErrorTitle = Result from lookup
    'sBtnText = Result from lookup

    Me.lbl_ErrorMessage = sErrorMessage
    Me.img_ErrorType.Picture = "C:/File Location/" & sErrorType & ".jpg"
    Me.Caption = sErrorTitle
    Me.btn_Action.Caption = sBtnText
End Sub
```

And the code for the button click

```
Private Sub btn_Action_Click()
    Dim sBtnAction      As String

''Look up the following from the Error Table
    'sBtnAction = Result from lookup

    Application.Run sBtnAction

End Sub
```

With this and some tweaking and messing with code, you can now have a custom error/message system that would allow you (or even the user) to set the font for the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please forgive me if I do not understand your answer well. First of all, do you mean that MsgBox in Access Form = system error boxes? I assumed yes. I tried on Windows 8. Message box font size can be changed (Start -> Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Fonts -> Change font size -> select Message box from the combobox, which Title bars is the default selection, then select the font size beside it, ranging from 6 to 24. Then click Apply). But I can't locate the same destination in Windows 7. Could you please show me the path?

Comment: Secondly, I'm a beginner in VBA. I do not quite understand your alternative in "trap the error in VBA and display your own messages via a UserForm, which would allow you to control the message and the font". Could you please show me samples of codes or direct me to the website that provides related information. I can't get it from Google. Thank you very much.

Comment: Response for first comment: It's the same, only it allows you to change by a percentage, not a specific size. But like I mentioned, it's not a good answer as each user would have to make this change, and since it is system wide, they might not want to make it.

Comment: to show you code, you'll need to show some of yours. How are you getting the message boxes? Is it an error? Is it the result of code you are running, or some other action that is being taken? Once we know that you can replace the message with a UserForm (see the VBA environment Insert > UserForm).

Comment: Some are just normal message boxes, such as: MsgBox "Add new part in NEW PART Table.", vbInformation, "Add New Part"; Some are for error handling, such as:     If countDuplicate > 0 Then
        MsgBox "A record of this Part ID already exist. No changes can be made.", vbCritical, "Duplicated Record"
        Me.Undo
    End If;
        If countName = 0 Then
            MsgBox " " & [txtGID] & " is not a valid EMPLOYEE." & " Re-enter GID", vbCritical, "Invalid GID"
            txtGID = Null
            dummy.SetFocus
            txtGID.SetFocus
        End If