# Reading error message for message box from table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am trying to display error message in MS Access which will get the error from one table. 
There is a table, having only one column which is having error records. I need to display all the records from table in message box of ms access.

I know how to get the message box but unable to find how to fetch records in the msg box

```
MsgBox "Errors are :" & vbCr & _
                "E.g. 000123", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
```

How can i get the values from table?

Comment: Read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887646/display-selected-records-on-message-box-in-the-form-of-microsoft-access-2013) and see if it helps you. I know it's a little different, but the concepts are there.

Answer (score 2):

Add this sub in your form or a stand alone module :

```
Public Sub DisplayErrors()

    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim strErrors as string

    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyErrorTable")

    If Not RS.BOF Then
        While Not RS.EOF
            strErrors = strErrors & RS!MyErrorField & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
            RS.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing

    MsgBox "Errors are : " & vbCrLf & strErrors , vbCritical + vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Replace *`MyErrorTable`* and *`MyErrorField`*  with the name of your table and it's unique field containing the errors.

Then call your sub from anywhere with :

```
DisplayErrors
```

Comment: Its working fine for one error record, I am having 20 records in that table so it is throwing 20 error msg box. I need all 20 records in one msg box

Comment: I Adapted the code to achieve what you want. Mark the post as "Answered" if it's OK and also try to search a litlle bit more by yourself next time ;-)